# char can not be dereferenced charAt().compareTo()

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
    String time= in.nextLine();
    String arr[]=time.split(":");
   // System.out.println(arr[0]);
    String PM="P";
    if(!(arr[2].charAt(2)).compareTo(PM)) //I get an error here 
        {
        arr[0]+=12;
        System.out.print(arr[0]+":"+arr[1]+":"+arr[2]);
    }
    if((arr[2].charAt(2)).compareTo(PM)!=0) //I get an error here
        {
        System.out.print(arr[0]+":"+arr[1]+":"+arr[2]);
    }
}
```

Please help me remove errors !
What i basically have to check is if time input has AM or PM.

Comment: _charAt_ returns a character, which is a primitive type variable. You can't invoke a method (here, _compareTo_) on this kind of variable.

Comment: You can simply check arr[2].contains(PM);

Comment: "What i basically have to check is if time input has AM or PM." Then use a date/time library! There is no need to reinvent that particular wheel.

Answer (score 1):

`char` doesn't have a `compareTo` method - or any methods, for that matter, since it is a primitive.

You can compare primitives using relational operators like `<`, `>` and `==`.

Since `PM` is a single-character string, you can also change its type to char:

```
char PM = 'P';
```

and then just use `!=` to compare, e.g.

```
if (arr[2].charAt(2) != PM) {
   // .. whatever.
```

Answer (score 0):

`.charAt()` returns a `char`, and the `char` behaves like at smaller `int` try to use this:

```
   if(!(arr[2].charAt(2) == PM.charAt(0))) {
    ...
```

Instead of:

```
   if(!(arr[2].charAt(2)).compareTo(PM))
```